# Accessing button using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, button, element

[image: HTML Code]

I am attempting to click the button who's code is shown but it does not seem to be able to find the element. I am using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://windspeed.atcouncil.org/")

button2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('submit')
```

It does not seem to find the correct element, is there a better way to access the button?

Comment: `submit` as CSS selector will search for `select` tags, which is not what you want. Please check e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp for selector syntax. I guess in your case, you might want to `find_element_by_css_selector` for something like `[type=submit]`. But I would rather go with Kevin's answer and use (x)path to address within the page. Who knows what other buttons are hanging around. It's not the case on this page, but your snipplet will get more reusable when you use the more general pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xpath?

```
button2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Get Windspeed"]')
```